# How record Audio from Kinect with NAudio

Tags: c#, kinect, naudio

I would like to record audio from Kinect. I'm using `NAudio` library.

I found this code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Play Button
{
  fileName = "lastReplay.wav";            

  FileStream FS_Write = File.OpenWrite("lastReplay.wav");
  FS_Write.Close();

  int deviceNumber = sourceList.SelectedItems[0].Index;

  sourceStream = new NAudio.Wave.WaveIn();
  sourceStream.DeviceNumber = deviceNumber;
  sourceStream.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(44100,  
      NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.GetCapabilities(deviceNumber).Channels);

  NAudio.Wave.WaveInProvider waveIn = new
      NAudio.Wave.WaveInProvider(sourceStream);

  sourceStream.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs>
      (sourceStream_DataAvailable);
  waveWriter = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileWriter(fileName, sourceStream.WaveFormat);
  sourceStream.StartRecording();
}


private void sourceStream_DataAvailable(object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs e)
{
  if (waveWriter == null) return;
  waveWriter.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
  waveWriter.Flush();
}
```

When i start the kinect the audio channel need to be started, so I use this:

```
Stream audioStream  = this.sensor.AudioSource.Start();
```

How can I change the `button2_click` method for accepting audioStream?

Comment: Since button2_click serves as an event it must have the method signature you provided. So there is no possibility to pass an extra argument to this event except overriding the button class an implement a custom event of the click event

Comment: Ok, but i can use audioStream with global variable, so i can use it

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem, the code is this:

```
   static void WriteWavHeader(Stream stream, int dataLength)
        {
            //We need to use a memory stream because the BinaryWriter will close the underlying stream when it is closed
            using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(64))
            {
                int cbFormat = 18; //sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX)
                WAVEFORMATEX format = new WAVEFORMATEX()
                {
                    wFormatTag = 1,
                    nChannels = 1,
                    nSamplesPerSec = 16000,
                    nAvgBytesPerSec = 32000,
                    nBlockAlign = 2,
                    wBitsPerSample = 16,
                    cbSize = 0
                };

                using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(memStream))
                {
                    //RIFF header
                    WriteString(memStream, "RIFF");
                    bw.Write(dataLength + cbFormat + 4); //File size - 8
                    WriteString(memStream, "WAVE");
                    WriteString(memStream, "fmt ");
                    bw.Write(cbFormat);

                    //WAVEFORMATEX
                    bw.Write(format.wFormatTag);
                    bw.Write(format.nChannels);
                    bw.Write(format.nSamplesPerSec);
                    bw.Write(format.nAvgBytesPerSec);
                    bw.Write(format.nBlockAlign);
                    bw.Write(format.wBitsPerSample);
                    bw.Write(format.cbSize);

                    //data header
                    WriteString(memStream, "data");
                    //bw.Write(dataLength);
                    bw.Write(dataLength);
                    memStream.WriteTo(stream);
                }
            }
        }
```

But with this method i should know before the time of file audio. I put dataLength parameter. If i use this code it found but now i would like to use this method never dataLength parameter because i don't know before the duration of file Audio, how can I modify it?